# How to make a link stay styled when not rolled over?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I have a carousel at [this page](http://clanbz.net84.net/) and I was wondering how to keep whichever carousel page's link stay styled when that section is being viewed. A clear example would be all the links are grayed out except for the section of the carousel your on.

Comment: You have the weirdest dummy text. I'm sure one of them just said "`i will kill you `" :)

Comment: Yea... that's what happens when you stay up til 4 am working on something. :-)

Comment: Interesting how everything on that link is lorem ipsum except for "My name is CIcily and i am a whore" and "I will kill you".  #wtf

Comment: The plugin you're using provides a way to do this (it adds a class `current` to the active tab's button). But, you're using the plugin in a bizarre way. You're making your own (additional) buttons, and triggering a `.click()` on the "real buttons": `<a class="tab1" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('[href=#1]').click();">News</a>` - that's not how you should be doing it :/

Comment: It's because it would not let me edit the text of the real buttons

Answer (score 1):

You could make it simpler by giving all of your tab links a class (e.g. `<a ... class="tab tab1">`)

You could then use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.tab').click(function() { $('.tab').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active'); }); 
});
```

And add CSS:

```
a.tab { color:#999; }
a.tab.active { color:#000; }
```

Comment: Wow great, but how would I have it open up to "News" already being highlighted?

Comment: You can just manually give it the active class in markup. jQuery will clear it when one of them is clicked. `<a ... class="tab tab1 active">`